# Basic method to export cells values from GridView to SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, database, devexpress

I need to read i little course about how to export a gridView in DevExpress to a SQL table..
like the values First Name, Father Name, Last Name to a table Employee and i have many rows..
how can I loop into every row and send data to the database..

Thx in advance

I tried this code:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO Emp (@FName, @MName,@LName, @Code, @TaxNb, @SSN, @EmploymentType, @DOB, @MarStat, @RegNum, @BadgeNum, @HireDate, @TaxSince, @HireSince, @ArEmpName, @ArFatherName, @ArLastName, ArPayUnit)";

DataTable table = new DataTable();
try
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"workstation id = PC-PC; user id=sa;Password=sapassword; data source=pc-pc; persist security info=True;initial catalog=CleanPayrollTest2");

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.InsertCommand = command;
    connection.Open();
    // for (int i =0; i< gridView3.RowCount; i++)
    //{
    //command.Parameters.Add(@FirstName, gridView3.GetRowCellValue(i,gridView3.Columns));
    //adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //}

    SqlParameter[] MyParams = new SqlParameter[28];

    MyParams[0] = new SqlParameter("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    MyParams[0].SourceColumn = FirstName;
    command.Parameters.Add("@FName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);

    MyParams[1] = new SqlParameter("@MName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    MyParams[1].SourceColumn = FatherName;

    MyParams[2] = new SqlParameter("@LName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
    MyParams[2].SourceColumn = LastName;
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you what I tried..
That code is not giving me any error.. but ''m not getting any data in the database

Comment: Why don't you use Google before asking? Here is an article (http://snipplr.com/view/29247/) which describes process very well.

Comment: Look into using Linq and Stored procedures, far nicer and cleaner approach

Comment: Why do you need to use a `SqlDataAdapter`? Just use `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` to perform the insert. Also probably you should use a couple of [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [SqlDataAdapter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879f39d8.aspx):

> The SqlDataAdapter, serves as a bridge between a DataSet and SQL
>   Server for retrieving and saving data.

In the scenario you described, there is no such need for a *"bridge"*. You just use a `SqlCommand`, add the collection of `SqlParameter` to it, and then call `ExecuteNonQuery()` to perform the insert.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"workstation id = PC-PC; user id=sa;Password=sapassword; data source=pc-pc; persist security info=True;initial catalog=CleanPayrollTest2"))
{
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();  
            for (int i =0; i< gridView3.RowCount; i++)
            {
                SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
                // TODO: handle name accordingly (MName, LName etc.)
                parameter.ParameterName = "@FName";
                // TODO: handle type accordingly
                parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar; 
                parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                // TODO: use the field name accordingly
                parameter.Value = Convert.ToString(gridView3.GetRowCellValue(i, "FieldName"));
                // add the parameter to the command
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            // TODO: handle the exception
        }

    }
}
```

Remark: you should dispose your SQL related objects in the code - a convenient way to do that is to use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statements.

Comment: I am getting this error: "Must declare the variable @FName
Any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line: `command.Parameters.Add(parameter);`. Now it's fixed.